# Как подключить стили плагина в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть самописная тема. Все стили и скрипты шаблона подключаются через wp_head() с соответствующим описанием в functions.php.

Шорткод из плагина вывожу на страницу шаблона через do_shortcode(), но выводится только HTML-код плагина, без js/css.

Если проделываю аналогичные действия в теме по умолчанию, то подхватываются все стили автоматом и плагин работает нормально.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Плагин подключить через do_shortcode() невозможно. Переформулируйте вопрос, чтобы вас можно было понять.

Comment: Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Comment: как я могу отредактировать вопрос?

Comment: Ниже вопроса есть кнопка Править http://take.ms/GWtqv

Comment: Плагин тоже ваш, не пойму? Стили плагина надо подключать через wp_enqueue_script() в файле плагина.

Comment: А, кажется, я понял. В вашей самописной теме отсутствует wp_head(). Вот это почитайте, в общем: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688720/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-wordpress/688721#688721

Comment: А еще может отсутствовать wp_footer(), тогда WP не подключит скрипты, назначенные к выводу в футере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, проблема в том, что в вашей самописной теме отсутствуют вызовы `wp_head()` или `wp_footer()`. Как это влияет на плагины? Попробуем рабозобраться.

Плагин подключает свои стили через вызовы `wp_enqueue_style()` в теле плагина. На самом деле, эта функция не выводит строку подключения типа `<link rel='stylesheet' ...` немедленно, она лишь заносит информацию во внутренние структуры данных WordPress о том, что такая строка должна быть выведена в хедере или футере сайта.

Сам вывод производится в момент вызова функций `wp_head()` или `wp_footer()` соответственно. Код `wp_head()` из `wp-includes/general-template.php`

```
function wp_head() {
    /**
     * Prints scripts or data in the head tag on the front end.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    do_action( 'wp_head' );
}
```

В файле есть `wp-includes/default-filters.php` есть определение этого действия. Там много чего, в том числе

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_print_styles', 8 );
```

Функция `wp_print_styles()` и выводит скрипты.

Аналогично работает и `wp_footer()`.

Таким образом, если в вашей теме отсутствуют вызовы `wp_head()` или `wp_footer()`, все благие намерения плагинов вывести свои скрипты успехом не увенчаются.

Comment: Ага, wp_head() был, а wp_footer() не было. Благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

подключение css из плагина... [wp_register_style](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_register_style)
а так проверить пути... [get_template_directory](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_register_style)

Comment: Нет проблем с выводом стилей шаблона, есть проблема с выводом стилей плагина.
Можно конечно подключить стили плагина отдельно в function.php, но это вроде как не правильно.