# Изменение тегов вывода меню в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю на сайте вывод меню через wp_nav_menu. Сайт на WordPress. WP автоматом выводит меню со своими тегами **ul** и **li**, и своими классами. Мне они не подходят, подскажите как можно либо к этим тегам прикрутить свои классы, либо вместо этих тегов вывести свои. Я пробовал заменить теги своими - добился того что нет возможности передать класс тегу . Код меню в оригинале:

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
            <a href="#" class="nav-menu--link active-link">Главная</a>
            <a href="catalog.html" class="nav-menu--link">Продукция</a>
            <a href="about.html" class="nav-menu--link">О компании</a>
            <a href="contacts.html" class="nav-menu--link">Контакты</a>
        </nav>
```

и то что я намудрил в функции:

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location' => 'top',
            'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
            'container' => 'false',
            'items_wrap' =>'<a class="nav-menu--link active-link"> </a>',
        ) );
        ?>
        </nav>
```

Ссылка на многострадальный сайт:
http://kaauto.volodysm.beget.tech/

Судя по тому, что я читал о механизме вывода меню - мне нужно будет писать свой Walker, глянул его исходник - понял что это плохая идея. Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты решения, второй день уже сижу...

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - задайте классы прямо в админке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не надо уходить от структуры меню WordPress - через ul и li. Это правильное построение меню, особенно когда есть несколько уровней вложенности. Всё, что вы хотите, можно сделать классами.

Comment: все бы хорошо если бы так можно было. У меня тема созданная и при поставлении отметки в классах css - внизу доп-поле не появляется. получается надо тогда править functions.php Многовато чести для меню...

Comment: Это вы основательно поломали WP своей темой. Вот только что проверил на абсолютно пустой теме, с нуля - если в functions.php ест вызов `register_nav_menus()`, то в админке появляется возможность редактировать меню и добавляются классы css. Я даже не знаю, что надо сделать, чтобы эти классы НЕ появлялись.

Comment: а можете эту тему скинуть?

Comment: Да там два файла всего. Тут описывал тему zero: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688720/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-wordpress/688721#688721

Answer (score 0):

Функция `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` (документация https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/) позволяет получить все элементы указанного меню и потом работать с ними так, как вам будет удобно