# Не подключаются стили к WordPress - помогите

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Я уже битый час мучаюсь с подключением стилей к WordPress, уже перепробовал буквально все. Если кто знает, как решить эту проблему, то, пожалуйста, отпишите. В коде вроде все правильно, но все равно ничего не работает.

```
<?php

function xafori_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xafori_scripts');

?>
```

Comment: Вангую: тема самописная, в header.php отсутствует вызов wp_head()

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688720/220220