# Не подключает стили в WordPress

Tags: wordpress, хостинг

Подскажите, пожалуйста, - я установил на хостинге вордпресс, сейчас устанавливаю свою тему, в файле `index.php`, в headеr есть строка которая подключает стили

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>">
</head>
```

Так вот, у меня файлов .css 4 штуки, когда я написал эту строку, то подключил только один файл стилей, а нужно 4, для остальных трёх написал ту же строку, но результата не было. Как мне подключить оставшиеся 3 файла стилей?

Comment: Полагаю, вы неправильно создали `header.php`. Скорее всего, там нет `wp_head();` Почитайте вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688720/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-wordpress/688721#688721

Comment: спасибо вам огромное))) действительно, в файле header.php нужно было просто вставить <?php wp_head(); ?> и все заработало))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bloginfo( `stylesheet.url` )
```

возвращает url файла темы `style.css`. И всё. Для подключения других файлов стилей надо указывать их url.

Но, вообще-то это всё неправильно. Так не надо делать. В WordPress есть специальные функции: `wp_enqueue_style()` - для подключения стилей, `wp_enqueue_script()` - для подключения скриптов. Они подключают файлы с учётом зависимостей между ними. Например:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ball-clip-rotate-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ball-clip-rotate.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-theme-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.min.css',
    array(
        'font-awesome',
        'ball-clip-rotate-style',
    )
);
```

В примере указано, что `style.css` зависит от `font-awesome` и `ball-clip-rotate` и должен быть запущен после них.

Подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_style) и [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script).

Кроме того, типичной ошибкой начинающих знакомиться с WordPress является попытка написания своей собственной темы. Это порочный путь, который вас мало чему научит, и заставит спотыкаться на массе проблем, подобных приведённой в вопросе.

Берите любую тему из официального репозитория, создавайте от неё [дочернюю](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html), и постепенно, шаг за шагом, разбирайтесь, как всё устроено, заглядывая в код основной темы.

Comment: +150. ... И здесь ;) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-wordpress/763199#763199