# Почему не подключаются стили css в вордпресс?

Tags: css, wordpress

Всем снова привет, подскажите плиз, что неправильно делаю. В теме wordpress в файле functions.php прописал функцию подключения стилей, но страница все равно чисто HTML.Вроде все правильно прописал. Все фвйлы находятся по директориям в коде, как надо

```
<?php

function register_styles(){
    wp_register_style('pockets-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() '/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('pockets-bootstrap');

    wp_register_style('pockets-mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('pockets-mainstyle');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'register_styles');
?>
```

Comment: Потому что, скорее всего, тема самописная, а в header.php отсутствует вызов wp_head(). Почитайте мой пост на эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/688720/220220

Comment: Спасибо, помогли!

Comment: Если помогло, можно ответить плюсом вопрос и ответ по ссылке )